# Load website into app using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

How do I load a website into a Phonegap app? I've created an index.html file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
         window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://secured.knowsley.gov.uk', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }
</script>
```

and a config.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode = "10" 
    version     = "1.0.0" >

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>PhoneGap Example</name>

<description>
    An example for phonegap build docs. 
</description>

<author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    Hardeep Shoker 
</author>

<allow-navigation href="https://secured.knowsley.gov.uk/*" />
```

But when I deploy the .apk to an Android device and open the app nothing is happening - blank white page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you install inAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: how? please post a code sample.

Comment: so the answer is no, right? go to the inAppBrowser documentation and read how to install it

Comment: thanks, got it. if you want an upvote post this as the answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using netbean ide to develop ur app

Follow this step to add ur plugin.

if you open project properties (right click on your project->properties) and select Cordova->Plugins, there is a note that you can edit [projectFolder]/nbproject/plugins.properties file to manually add plugins. Add following line for InAppBrowser

org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser=https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

and build your project.

Hope it solve ur problem.
I a also having problem to make this inappbrowser latest version i installed work with cordova 5.4.1

If yours work let me know and guide me on ow to go about it